# How to handle iframe cacheissue in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-2013

I am displaying some web pages in a SharePoint site by using an iFrame with the help of Content Editor Web Part.As per my requirement i need to pass the SharePoint Login Credentials like User Email & Title to web pages that are being displayed by using iFrame. So for this purpose i am passing those values by appending them as query string parameters to the src attribute of iframe. Now the problem is if suppose two users access the site simultaneously with a slightest gap of fraction of seconds of time the second(2nd) user is getting first user's credentials. I don't know how to solve this issue.Anyone can help me regarding this scenario.Also if anyone knows any other approach other the Query Strings in this context please suggest me them

Comment: It sounds like you need to rethink the whole process...

Comment: Hey @JamesHill what do u mean by rethink. Is my approach not good or something else ?